# Using Page Name or URL Properties for Handlebar If Statements in Big Commerce templates

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I'm currently working on a BigCommerce theme using their [Stencil framework](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/what-is-stencil). It leverages Handlebars.js for some logic already and I'm trying to use it to show specific html on specific pages.

Looking at the [documentation](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/pages-object) I can see there is a "pages" object and that I should be able to name or URL to do what I need to do.

I cannot figure out the syntax to get the page name or url to run the iff against. I can succesfully get it to do what I want by testing if it's a page content type, but not any of the type properties.

```
{{#if pages }}
 ... do foo here
{{/if}}
```

What I want to do is something like

```
{{#if pages.url '===' 'about' }}
 ... do foo here
{{/if}}

{{#if pages.url '===' 'service' }}
 ... do foo different here
{{/if}}
```

Comment: have you tried `page.title`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are actually using the wrong Object Model for the data that you are trying to pull. The first word of your handlebars object should be "page" and not "pages". This will pull any content or data from the static pages that you build in the back office. (AKA the WYSIWYG)

Here is a link to the docs of the model that you want.  https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/page-content-object

For Example:

```
{{{page.title}}}
{{{page.content}}}
```

Note that I am using 3 handlebar on each side to escape the HTML on the WYSIWYG. Let me know if you need any other help.